# Can I share private data between two users of same peers in hyperledger-fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Let's say I have 3 users U1, U2 and U3 all belongs to the same peers and I want to share data between U1 and U3 which U2 can't see. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use collections_config.json to specify your policies as you want and save data to respective collections.

```
"name": "<Collection for U1, U3>",
"policy": "AND('U1MSP.member', 'U3MSP.member')",
```

and for rest

```
"name": "<collection for all other>",

"policy": "OR('U1MSP.member', 'U2MSP.member', 'U3MSP.member')",
```